# Selenium Selector is not consistent returning all options sometimes and other times not?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, indexing

I apologize ahead of time for the length of this question but I want to give enough context.

I've been running in circles trying to figure out why this is happening. I'm indexing all the dropdown values of a bookstore and have done so successfully for 'departments' and 'course_nums' but when I try to do the same thing for 'sections' relative to the 'course_nums' it returns some of the lists of sections and fails to return others. I've seen alternative methods of getting options from Selector on Stack and Documentation but I've had no success with these methods.

When a dropdown is selected the attributes of the HTML get an additional id called
`<option value="001" data-select2-id="703">001</option>`

So I've tried to just use Selector without first clicking on the dropdown (by commenting out the DriverWait before the Selector in fill_sections()) but this does not work although the element is present in the DOM.

When run, it will sometimes return the corresponding course sections and other times an empty list of sections, but each course number should have at least 1 section. As I reviewed the automated input it's as if it goes too fast on *some* course numbers which might cause it to miss fetching all options, but I'm not sure. I'm stumped because this works for every other fetch for the departments and course numbers relative to the department.

Fair warning, let it run until it prints the arrays otherwise it starts this infinite loop for some reason when you hit
`control-c` and I honestly don't know why.

Upon request from the comments, here is the entire script relevant to indexing the departments, course_nums, and sections...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from pprint import pprint
import sys
import time
import os

# path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
# sys.path.append(path)
URL = "https://gmu.bncollege.com/course-material/course-finder"
# page = requests.get(URL)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
departments = []
courses = []
sections = []

def fill_departments():
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div'))
            )
        element.click()
            # print('selected department drop down')

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/span/span[1]/input'))
        )
        selector = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/select"))
        options = selector.options

        for index in range(1, len(options)):
            # (index - 1) to ensure proper indexing of departments
            dep_dict = {"index": index-1, "department": options[index].text}
            departments.append(dep_dict)
    except:
        return 1

    return 0

def fill_course_nums(department, index):
    try:
        # /html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div'))
        )
        element.click()
        # print('clicked on course drop down')

        # /html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/select
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/span[2]/span/span[1]/input'))
        )

        selector = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/select"))
        options = selector.options

        courses = []
        for ind in range(0, len(options)):
            if (options[ind].text == "Select"):
                continue
            course_obj = {"index": ind - 1, "course_num": options[ind].text}
            courses.append(course_obj)

        departments[index]['courses'] = courses
    except:
        return 1

    return 0

def fill_sections(dep_index, index):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div'))
        )
        element.click()

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/span[2]/span/span[1]/input'))
        )

        # selector_s = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.find_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/select"))))
        selector_s = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/select"))

        options_s = selector_s.options

        # # 
        sections = []
        for op in options_s:
            if (op.text == "Select"):
                continue
            sections.append(op.text)

        departments[dep_index]['courses'][index]['sections'] = sections

    except:
        return 1
    return 0
def select_term(term):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div'))
        )
        element.click()
        # print('selected term drop down')

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]/span/span[2]/ul/li[2]'))
        )
        element.click()
        # print('selected spring 2022')

    except:
        return 1

    return 0
def clear_form():
    
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div/a'))
        )
        element.click()
    except:
        return 1
    return 0
def select_department(department):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div'))
        )
        element.click()
        # print('selected department drop down')

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span[2]/span/span[1]/input'))
        )
        element.send_keys(department)
        # print('typed department cs')

        element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        # print('selected department cs')
    except:
        return 1

    return 0

def select_course(course):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div'))
        )
        element.click()
        # print('clicked on course drop down')

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/span[2]/span/span[1]/input'))
        )
        element.send_keys(course)
        element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        # print('selected course 321')

    except:
        return 1

    return 0
def select_campus_info():
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/span'))
        )
        element.click()
        # print('found campus button')

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/span[2]/span/span[2]/ul/li[3]'))
        )
        element.click()
        # print('selected fairfax campus')

    except:
        return 1

    return 0
```

How these methods are run in main()

```
def main():
    start = time.time()
    driver.get("https://gmu.bncollege.com/course-material/course-finder")

    while(select_campus_info()):
        print('selecting campus')

    while(select_term("spring")):
        print('selecting term')
    while(fill_departments()):
        print("filling departments")

    for dep in range(0, len(departments)):
        if (dep != 0):
            while(select_term("spring")):
                print('selecting term')

        while(select_department(departments[dep]['department'])):
            print("trying (dep)")

        while(fill_course_nums(departments[dep]['department'], departments[dep]['index'])):
            print("filling courses")

        while(clear_form()):
            print("clearing")

        # break here after 3 to limit filling all courses for debugging purposes
        if (dep >= 3):
            break

    while(select_term("spring")):
        print('selecting term')

    for dep in range(0, 3):
        if (dep != 0):
            while(select_term("spring")):
                print('selecting term')

        while(select_department(departments[dep]['department'])):
            print("trying (dep)")

        for course in range(0, len(departments[dep]['courses'])):

            while(select_course(departments[dep]['courses'][course]['course_num'])):
                print("trying (cnum)")

            while(fill_sections(dep, course)):
                print('filling (sections)')

        while(clear_form()):
            print('clearing form.')

            

    pprint(departments[0])
    pprint(departments[1])
    pprint(departments[2])


    # fill_textbook_info('spring', 'CS', 310, '002')

    # curUrl = driver.current_url
    # print(curUrl)

    time.sleep(100)
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: first you could display html to see if you have this element. Maybe it needs more time to create all elements. You could also display exceptions to see what exactly happend `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: better put all code in one minimal working example so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: Just added. Hope this helps, should be able to run once your env has all dependencies.

Comment: you use so many `while` - so in some situations it may run one of them forever. You should use `if` to run it only once. OR you should use `for x in range(3):` to run only 3 times and if it can't get then skip rest of code.

Comment: to make code more readable you could use `return True`/`return False` instead of `return 1`/`return 0`

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and usually problem was to fast running code - and it needed `time.sleep()` in some places - especially after sending `ENTER` (it used 1 second because 0.5 second was too small)

---

I put full code because I organized code in different way (I use nested `for`-loops`) and I used different XPATH (I tried to make them shorter and similar with different functions).

I also put all function at the beginning and put in order of use in `main()`

I also don't use global list `departaments` but I return list from function and assign to local variable. And later I do the same with courses and sections.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from pprint import pprint
import time

# --- functions ---

def select_campus(driver, word="Tech"):
    print('[select_campus] start')
    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="bned-campus-select"]//span[@class="selection"]/span'))
        ).click()
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//li[contains(text(), "{word}")]'))
        ).click()

        time.sleep(0.5)  # time for JavaScript to create `<select>`

    except Exception as ex:
        print('[select_campus] Exception:', ex)
        return False

    return True


def select_term(driver, term):
    print('[select_term] start')

    try:

        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "term")]//span[@class="selection"]/span'))
        ).click()

        time.sleep(0.5)  # time for JavaScript to create `<select>`
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//div[contains(@class, "term")]//li[contains(text(), "{term}")]'))
        ).click()

        time.sleep(0.5)  # time for JavaScript to create `<select>`

    except Exception as ex:
        print('[select_term] Exception:', ex)
        return False

    return True
    
    
def get_all_departments(driver):
    print('[get_all_departments] start')

    departments = []   
     
    try:
        #select [2]
        all_options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '((//div[@role="table"]//div[@role="row"])[2]//select)[2]//option')

        for index, option in enumerate(all_options[1:], 1):
            item = {"index": index, "department": option.text}
            departments.append(item)
        
        time.sleep(0.5)  # time for JavaScript to create `<select>`

    except Exception as ex:
        print('[get_all_departments] Exception:', ex)
        
    return departments


def select_department(driver, department):
    print('[select_department] start')

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@role="table"]//div[@role="row"])[2]//div[contains(@class, "department")]//span[@class="selection"]/span'))
        ).click()

        time.sleep(0.5)  # time for JavaScript to create `<select>`

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@role="table"]//div[@role="row"])[2]//div[contains(@class, "department")]//input'))
        )
        element.send_keys(department)
        element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        
        time.sleep(1)  # time for JavaScript to create `<select>`
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[select_department] Exception:', ex)
        return False

    return True


def get_all_courses(driver):
    print('[get_all_courses] start')

    courses = []

    try:
        #select [3]
        all_options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '((//div[@role="table"]//div[@role="row"])[2]//select)[3]//option')

        for index, option in enumerate(all_options[1:], 1):
            item = {"index": index, "section": option.text}
            courses.append(item)

    except Exception as ex:
        print('[get_all_courses] Exception:', ex)

    return courses

    
def select_course(driver, course):
    print('[select_course] start')
    
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@role="table"]//div[@role="row"])[2]//div[contains(@class, "course")]//span[@class="selection"]/span'))
        )
        element.click()

        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@role="table"]//div[@role="row"])[2]//div[contains(@class, "course")]//input'))
        )
        element.send_keys(course)
        element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        time.sleep(1)  # time for JavaScript to create `<select>`
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[select_course] Exception:', ex)
        return False

    return True


def get_all_sections(driver):
    print('[get_all_sections] start')

    sections = []

    try:
        #select [4]
        all_options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '((//div[@role="table"]//div[@role="row"])[2]//select)[4]//option')


        for index, option in enumerate(all_options[1:], 1):
            #item = {"index": index, "course": option.text}
            sections.append(option.text)

    except Exception as ex:
        print('[get_all_sections] Exception:', ex)

    return sections


def clear_form(driver):
    print('[clear_form] start')
   
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[@class="js-clear-row"]'))
        ).click()
        
        time.sleep(1)  # time for JavaScript to clear elements
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[clear_form] Exception:', ex)
        return False

    return True
    
    
def main():

    URL = "https://gmu.bncollege.com/course-material/course-finder"

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #options.headless = True
    #options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    # options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.maximize_window()

    start = time.time()
    
    driver.get(URL)

    select_campus(driver)
    select_term(driver, "Spring")

    departments = get_all_departments(driver)
        
    print('departments:')
    pprint(departments[:4])        

    for dep in departments[:4]: #  3 to limit filling all courses for debugging purposes
        print(dep)

        select_department(driver, dep['department'])

        print(dep)
        dep['courses'] = get_all_courses(driver)

        print('departments:')
        pprint(departments[:4])        

        for course in dep['courses']:
            select_course(driver, course['course'])

            course['sections'] = get_all_sections(driver)

            print('departments:')
            pprint(departments[:4])        

        #clear_form(driver)   # DON'T use it

    # --- display ---
    
    for dep in departments[:4]:
        pprint(dep)

    end = time.time()
    print('time:', end - start)

    input('Press ENTER to close')  # to keep open browser and check elements in DevTools
    
    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. This is good but when you try and run it, it will very rarely be successful resulting in having to rerun many times. This is why I had the loops to do it until it was successful? Is this not the right way to keep trying?

Comment: I didn't have to run it again - I had to only make longer `sleep` when JavaScript needed longer time to update data. But you have `WebDriverWait` to wait longer - and using loop seems useless. If it couldn't find in 1 second then use 5 seconds or 30 seconds. But if you couldn't get in some short time then maybe you never get it and using endless loop is only problem - it is better to resign for some time instead of runing it forever.